# xslt remove p element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XML file. I would like to import the content of the DESCRIPTION node tag
without the `<P>` tag in XSLT.

```
<DESCRIPTION>
    <P>A pagina 3, modificare:</P>
    <P>carte per il diporto - Leisure crafts</P>
    <P>in:</P>
    <P>
    <STRONG>Carte Nautiche in Kit - Nautical Charts in </STRONG>
    </P>
</DESCRIPTION>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:if test="last()&gt;1"> 
<span style=" font-family:Arial; line-height:0; ">
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), &apos;)&apos;)"/>
</span>                         
</xsl:if> 
<xsl:for-each select="NTC_CATALOGUEINSTRUCT"> 
<xsl:for-each select="DESCRIPTION">
    <span style="text-align:justify; margin-bottom:0pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>                              </span>   
     </xsl:for-each>                    
</xsl:for-each>
```

The output of this XML ---> XSL file is:

```
1)
    A pagina 3, modificare:
    carte per il diporto - Leisure crafts     charts...............................................51
    in:
    Carte Nautiche in Kit - Nautical Charts in Kit.........................................51
```

I would like:

```
1) A pagina 3, modificare: <------((((( look in the same line ))))))
carte per il diporto - Leisure crafts        charts...............................................51
    in:
    Carte Nautiche in Kit - Nautical Charts in Kit.........................................51
```

Comment: Hi, could you format your question properly, to only have the input/output in code blocks? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help. I would edit it for you but I can't tell exactly what output you want!

Comment: 1) A pagina 3, modificare :

Comment: now i had this: 1) and at the next rows A pagina 3, modificare. I woul all at the same row. this problema become of P tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Don't copy P elements themselves but do output their contents. 
       Enumerate the descriptions. -->
  <xsl:template match="P">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::P) = 0">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::DESCRIPTION) + 1"/>
      <xsl:text>) </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML:

```
<DESCRIPTION>
  <P>A pagina 3, modificare:</P>
  <P>carte per il diporto - Leisure crafts</P>
  <P>in:</P>
  <P>
    <STRONG>Carte Nautiche in Kit - Nautical Charts in </STRONG>
  </P>
</DESCRIPTION>
```

produces the following output:

```
  1) A pagina 3, modificare:
  carte per il diporto - Leisure crafts
  in:

    Carte Nautiche in Kit - Nautical Charts in
```

which I *think* is what you want.

Comment: nothing because i had a lot od description that contain table.

Comment: you have mail adress ?

Comment: no i would like remove only p tag. there is case when i have in description table or oter element. he description node is created by editor of word . i woul like to delete onli p tag.

Comment: Please feel free to open another question, or add to your existing one, with an example of the XML that's causing a problem.

Comment: <DESCRIPTION>
        <P>Questa è una prova per vedere come si comporta la trasformazione quando incontra dei paragrafi vuoti.</P>
        <P>Dal prara precedente non c'è alcuna riga vuota.</P>
        <P> </P>
        <P>Ora ho lasciato sopra una riga vuota (ovvero un paragrafo vuoto). Sono sulla stessa riga e vediamo come si comporta. Ora lascio due righe vuote sotto.</P>
        <P> </P>
        <P> </P>
        <P> </P>
        <P>Sono andato giù di 3 invii, il che equivale ad aver lasciato 2 righe vuote ovvero 2 paragrafi che dovrabbero essere vuoti.</P>
    </DESCRIPTION>